# What about the number of deleted recent questions?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

This last month (early november-december) I have six questions in my box
**recent deleted questions.**

> **Question.** What about this box, what is its purpose? It is not a problem or yes could be a problem have a high number of deleted recent questions?  I've deleted by my decission these questions, some have negative score and another since these were bad questions. **Can I made this as user without problems** or always is better that the platform delete questions with negative score, and try have more careful with questions of bad quality?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Wow, 7 whole hours and nobody has jumped in to connect the title question with a massive campaign. Sure, the body of the post and nature of the solutions lend no credence to such a thing, but that was no barrier to the phenomenon up to this point...

Comment: Thanks @rschwieb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having deleted questions and posts in itself is not a big problem. There is some limit on how many posts you can delete in a give timeframe and there are some warnings and other measures to shield against vandalism by self-deletions, but overall you can self-delete content, no problem.

**But** having many negatively scored posts can be a problem, whether they are deleted or not, they count towards potential limiting or even partial bans on your posting abilities.

Thus, one way or another you should try to fix having posts that score negatively.

Comment: Very thanks much @quid this information is useful to me then. I say to you and there is no a joke, that I've read this solution after my second post today in this Meta, and yes at least in MathOverflow is a problem, since I had only two old questions and the platform launched the cited warning. I neccesarly respect MathOverflow, and users too but this is my truth (at this date these questions aren't **recent deleted questions**, they there no exists in my profile). Thanks.

Comment: Yes, old questions can still count towards bans. But also it seems it is just a warning. So you should not feel to intimitaded by  it. However you should still take it seriously.

Comment: Very thanks much, in my life and here I can be wrong, and I assume the consequences, but I like the idea to improve. What I love about this site is that my mistakes are exposed to all, and I can improve with help. Good Christmas.